# ASMX JSON WebService, changing property types and having old __type - error

Tags: c#, web-services, json, asmx

I have a .NET JSON web service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Item))]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Info))]
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(Details))]
public class API : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public Item[] GetItems()
    {
         ...
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool SaveItem(Item item)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

*Definition of classes is at the bottom of the message.*

There is a property `More` of type `Info` in `Item` class.

On the client side (HTML5) i'm calling `GetItems()`, and storing it in local storage, and periodically call `SaveItem`.

JSON data that i get on the client is something like:

```
[{"__type":"MyApp.API.Item","More":{"__type":"MyApp.API.Info","ID":1}}]
```

All fine so far.

The **problem** occurs when i change property `More` from type `Info` to type `Details` in `Item` class, i.e:

```
[Serializable]
public class Item 
{
    public Details More { get; set; } // <----- type changed from Info to Details
}
```

Since my client has the data cached, when i try to call `SaveItem` ASP.NET is throwing error:

```
 Cannot convert object of type 'MyApp.API.Info' to 'MyApp.API.Details'
```

**Question**: If there a solution to this (ideally keeping the ASMX web service, and not changing JSON data on the client)?

*Here's what the classes are:*

```
[Serializable]
public class Item 
{
    public Info More { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Details: Info, IDetails
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Info: IInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public interface IDetails: IInfo
{
    string Notes { get; }
}

public interface IInfo
{
    int ID { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the "_type":"object" you can have your method as `object` type. 
all this text would dissapear.